# Using Kotlin Duration with Java Time fluently

Tags: kotlin

What is purpose of Kotlin Duration when it isn't fluently compatible with java.time clasees?
When I need always use converter... Why aren't implements extenstion function over java classes which should intercept Kotlin Duration? Are there some fluent ways to use Kotlin Duration with java.time?

```kotlin
    OffsetDateTime.now().plus(1.days) // not working

    OffsetDateTime.now().plus(1.days.toJavaDuration()) // working
```

*NOTE: example not so good, in this case I can use plusDays... but I hope that ilustrate inflating of expresion*

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting). In the transcription, indicate the error with a comment showing what the tooltip says.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of [`kotlin.time.Duration`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/) to represent the duration between two instances in time - the same as [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

Note that some parts of [Kotlin Time are still experimental](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-experimental-time/), and require an opt-in for any Kotlin projects that aim to support Kotlin v1.5 or lower.

One benefit of `kotlin.time.Duration` is that it is multiplatform, and can be used in Java, JavaScript, Native, and (soon) WASM Kotlin projects. `java.time.Duration` can only be used in Java projects.

There are at least two ways to improve compatibility:

- Use [kotlinx-datetime](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime), a JetBrains library that can be used to completely replace Java Time.

  This would make working with temporals in Kotlin easier, but it might be a large amount of effort for not much gain. It might also not be possible if the existing codebase is very dependent on Java Time.
- Create a custom [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions), that make temporal operations more convenient. Using the [`plus()` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#arithmetic-operators) is a natural improvement.

  ```kotlin
  import java.time.OffsetDateTime
  import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds
  import kotlin.time.Duration.*
  import kotlin.time.*

  fun main() {
     val now = OffsetDateTime.now()
     println("now         : $now")
     println("now.plus(1s): ${now.plus(1.seconds.toJavaDuration())}")
     println("now + 1s    : ${now + 1.seconds}")
  }

  /** Adds [amountToAdd] to an [OffsetDateTime] */
  operator fun OffsetDateTime.plus(amountToAdd: Duration): OffsetDateTime =
     plus(amountToAdd.toJavaDuration())
  ```

  [*Run in Kotlin Playground*](https://pl.kotl.in/z7jqhWM_S)

Comment: thanks for clarifying, I understand that dependency on jvm is not wanted. But those extensions could be added by JB to extend java.time api, they did the same for many other java classes like String etc. I think it helps to more usage of kotlin time lib in jvm projects, because working with it is more fluent and Kotlin idiomatic